# How do I address my EE mobile bill doubling due to picture messages?

Tags: united-kingdom, mobile-phone-plans

I have multiple numbers on my EE mobile account, including children. We are all getting charged for every Picture Message sent which is now doubling the EE mobile monthly bill!

Other than simply saying to everyone "Stop sending picture messages" or "Why can't you use WhatsApp for this", how can I cost-effectively address this issue?

Comment: Not sure how this relates to personal finances, but have you considered asking your mobile carrier on solutions?

Comment: An unexpected doubling of your mobile phone bill with no apparent change in usage is a personal finance issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

EE Support state that Pictures and **Emojis(!)** are converted to the richer MMS format which incur a charge per message.

Therefore the following strategies occur:

1. Enforce use of simple characters on the Messages app. For the Google Messaging app on Samsung Galaxy S10, this is under the user icon, then Messages settings, then Advanced, then Use Simple Characters
2. Contact EE Support who have discretion to add 30 MMS for free each month to your tariff. Request this for all mobile numbers on the account
3. Use WiFi based messaging whenever possible
4. [Purchase an Add-on to your tariff for MMS](https://ee.co.uk/help/help-new/billing-usage-and-top-up/understanding-my-bill/why-is-my-bill-higher-than-normal)
5. Change your contract to one with free MMS

Comment: 6. Have the carrier block paid messaging.